# Equilibria of complex non linear system

Tags: python, sympy

When i run the following code i get

```
TypeError:  can't multiply sequence by non-int of type "Add'
```

Can anyone explain why I get this error?

```
from sympy.core.symbol import symbols
from sympy.solvers.solveset import nonlinsolve

x, y, z, r, R, a, m, n, b, k1, k2 = symbols('x,y,z,r,R,a,m,n,b,k1,k2', positive=True)

f1 = r * x * (1 - x / k1) - (a * z * x ** (n + 1)) / (x ** n + y ** n)
f2 = R * y * (1 - y / k2) - (b * z * y ** (n + 1)) / (x ** n + y ** n)
f3 = z * (a * x ** (n + 1) + b * y ** (n + 1)) / (x ** n + y ** n) - m * z
f = [f1, f2, f3]
nonlinsolve(f, [x, y, z])
```

Comment: This error indicates a bug. You should open an issue in the [SymPy issue tracker](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues) for it (if one doesn't already exist).

Answer (score 0):

The error message is not really descriptive but the full stack trace indicates where the problem was: SymPy tries to work with the expression as if it was a polynomial, and finds that impossible because the exponent n is a symbol rather than a concrete integer.

Simply put, SymPy does not have an algorithm for solving systems like that one (and I'm not sure if any CAS has).

When written in polynomial form, the system has monomials of total degree n+2. So, already for n = 1 this is utterly hopeless: a system of three cubic equations with three  unknowns.  SymPy can solve the case n = 0, and I wouldn't expect anything more than that.